# Show record only consists unique reference key with different values on the other column and also record not exist in other table

Tags: php, mysql

I already post this issue before but forgot to include with other situation, so i need to repost this back. Although i already tried with NOT EXIST and NOT IN, still not working.

i have table A as follow:-

```
id | room_id| room_status
 1 |   16    |  Out
 2 |   2     |  Out
 3 |   4     |  Out
 4 |   16    |   In
 5 |   3     |   In
 6 |   10    |   In
```

"Out" means the room is free to book. "In" means the room is occupied and cannot be selected.

Also have table B as follow:-

```
room_id  | Own_by
   2     | Comp A
   3     | Comp A
   4     | Comp A
  10     | Comp A
  16     | Comp A
  20     | Comp A
```

Desired output :-

```
room_id
   2
   4
   3
  20
```

Old issue: i would like to show room_id 3 also because it's currently been selected but also can change to other room which is room_id 2, 4 with room_status "Out". I don't want room_id 16, 10 to show up because they're not currently selected and already occupied. - this one already working, thanks to @P.Salmon and @GordonLinoff.

New issue : Also need to show room_id 20 which is not in table A. How can I show the desire output? Really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my previous answer you could drive from table b left joining to table a and testing for null (no entry at all in table a)

```
select id,t1.room_id,room_status
from t1
left join  t on t1.room_id = t.room_id
where (id = (select max(id) from t t2 where t2.room_id = t.room_id)
and (room_status = 'out' or t1.room_id = 3)) or
t.room_id is null;

+------+---------+-------------+
| id   | room_id | room_status |
+------+---------+-------------+
|    2 |       2 | Out         |
|    3 |       4 | Out         |
|    5 |       3 | In          |
| NULL |      20 | NULL        |
+------+---------+-------------+
```

Comment: Thank you @P.Salmon for the quick response. I did get that room_id 20 but other room_id which not related to the query seems to appear also. i just added this to the query to fulfill the desired output...  and t1.condition = 'Okay' and t1.belongsto = 'KJ-02-09-01' and  these other room_id which is not supposed to appear dont even meet that extra query that i just added but still they shows up in the output. I'm still working on it. Is there anything i'm  missing?

Comment: Can you add sample data including these conditions either by amending your question or to sqlfiddle and I'll have a look.

Comment: i already got solution to my prob. i need to use union all to combine two different queries and group them by ID. Anyway your ans also did help to solve my prob. Thank you @P.Salmon